# Cardinality of the zero locus of a degree 2 homogeneous polynomial on Z/2Z: avoiding Chevalley-Warning

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, roots, finite-fields

I have never developed sufficient knowledge in algebraic geometry but I ran into an apparently easy problem, so I apologise in advance if my question sounds naive.
Suppose to have a degree $2$ homogeneous (non-trivial) polynomial $p(\mathbf{x})=\sum\limits_{j=1}^n\sum\limits_{i=1}^ja_{ij}x_ix_j\in\mathbb{F}_2[\mathbf{x}]$ of $n$ variables, with $\mathbb{F}_2=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}=\{0,1\}$. If $n\geq3$, we can use Chevalley-Warning theorem to conclude that the zero locus of $p$ must have even cardinality, whence odd cardinality of the zero locus of $p$ may occur only in the cases $n=1,2$ (for $n=1$, $p(x)=x^2$ does the job while for $n=2$ we have four possibilities, $p(x)=xy,x(x+y),(x+y)y,x^2+xy+y^2$). Do you think that Chevalley-Warning theorem can be avoided in this particular case, to prove that for $n\geq3$ the zero locus has even cardinality?

Comment: A counting argument not unlike that in the proof of Chevalley-Warning is simple over $\Bbb{F}_2$: The sum of values of a monomial $x_{i_1}x_{i_2}\cdots x_{i_k}$ of degree $k$ in $n$ variables, $n>k$ so choose any $k$ out of the $n$ to appear as factors, obviously vanishes, because there is duplication (the value of a missing variable can be chosen freely). Consequently the same holds for any sum of such monomials, implying the claim.

Comment: A bit more can be said. In [tag:coding-theory] we often use the fact that a polynomial (homogeneous or not) of degree $r$ in $\Bbb{F}_2[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_m]$ has at least $2^{m-r}$ zeros and at least $2^{m-r}$ non-zeros. Furthermore, either extreme is achieved only when the exceptional locus is a coset of an $r$-dimensional subspace. Look up [Reed-Muller codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed%E2%80%93Muller_code) for more.